# Calling PL/SQL functions using JDBC in a Spring clone

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle, framework

I started to modify some old code and ended up creating a sort of spring jdbc framework.
I know just the most popular design pattern, so I was wondering if my design was good.
For example, to call store procedures, I created an interface `PlsqlParameter`, to hold in and out parameter and cycle them.
But for example, `InPlsqlParameter` is forced to implements `getItemFromStatement`, with no return (because it's not an output).

How can I improve my design?
[My project on github](https://github.com/czar82/LazyJdbc/tree/2154e06bfe04e93a18f93da23ca41c61e1eeee98)

the main method:

```
public void genericProcedure(Connection conn, String functionName, PlsqlParameter ... queryParams)  throws Exception
{
    CallableStatement cstm = null;

    String query = getQueryProcedure(functionName, queryParams).toString();     
    boolean paramEmpty = queryParams.length==1 && queryParams[0]==null;

    try
    {
        cstm = conn.prepareCall(query);
        int i=1;
        if (!paramEmpty)
        {
            for (PlsqlParameter ob:queryParams)
            {
                ob.setParameter(i++, cstm);
            }
        }

        cstm.execute();
        if (!paramEmpty)
        {
            i=1;
            for (PlsqlParameter ob:queryParams)
            {
                ob.getItemFromStatement(i++, cstm);
            }
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        traceErrorLog(e, query, (Object[])queryParams);
        throw e;

    } finally
    {
        if (cstm!=null)
        {
            cstm.close();
        }
    }
}
```

getItemFromStatement return null:

```
public class InPlsqlParameter <T> implements PlsqlParameter {

    ItemContainer<T> item;

    public InPlsqlParameter() {
        super();
    }


    public InPlsqlParameter(T item) {
        super();
        this.item = new SingleItem<T>(item);
    }

    public InPlsqlParameter(ItemContainer<T> item) {
        super();
        this.item = item;
    }

    @Override
    public void setParameter(int parameterIndex, CallableStatement cstm) throws SQLException {
        cstm.setObject(parameterIndex, item!=null ? item.getObject() : null);
    }

    @Override
    public ItemContainer<?> getItemFromStatement(int parameterIndex,
            CallableStatement cstm) throws Exception {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return item!=null ? item.toString() : "";
    }

}
```

This is ok:

```
public class OutPlsqlParameter implements PlsqlParameter {

    ItemContainer<?> item;

    public OutPlsqlParameter(ItemContainer<?> item) {
        super();
        this.item = item;
    }

    @Override
    public void setParameter(int parameterIndex, CallableStatement cstm) throws SQLException {
        item.setOutParameter(parameterIndex, cstm);
    }

    @Override
    public ItemContainer<?> getItemFromStatement(int parameterIndex, CallableStatement cstm) throws Exception
    {
        return item.getObjectFromStatement(parameterIndex, cstm);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return item!=null ? item.toString() : "";
    }

}
```

Comment: Why don't you use jdbcTemplate? It already have all these features implemented.

Comment: I know, I just started to modify and refactor some old code and ended with this. However it's a good way to get practicing and I like it :D